# Как скачать репозиторий без установки Git на комп

Tags: git, github

Есть ли способ работать с Git на компе где нет установленного десктопного Git? Дело в том, что в учебном заведении где я учусь, нельзя устанавливать проги (нужны права админа). нужна возможность работать в терминале, скачивать репозитории (git clone http...) итд.

как тогда быть? есть ли способ работать с Git без установки проги ?

Comment: Можно нажать кнопку `Clone or download`, и скачать репозиторий в виде архива. Если нужна работа через Git, то нужен Git, клиент именно GitHub использовать не обязательно.

Comment: нужна возможность работать в терминале, скачивать репозитории (git clone http...) итд. Если постоянно скачивать через сайт, какой смысл тогда вообще в GitHub, в такой случае есть всякие облачные хранения вроде drive или dropbox

Comment: GitHub это сайт такой, его совсем не нужно устанавливать. )) Но понятно, что вы имели в виду программу Git.

Comment: @NickVolynkin позанудствую https://desktop.github.com/ :)

Comment: @andreymal там всё равно гит под капотом ))

Comment: *rsync -e ssh* или просто *rsync*, только для работы с репозиторием нужен клиент. Кстати, VS работает через libgit2

Answer (score 4):

В репозитории есть кнопка, чтобы скачать или склонировать. При нажатии на нее можно выбрать скачать на комп в виде архива например

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: да, я знаю, но мне нужна возможность работать через терминал

Comment: @Gusto ну так вопрос же был как скачать репо...а чтобы работать через терминал, нужен гитовский клиент.

Answer (score 4):

Можно скачать портативную версию Git, и работать из нее.

Для этого переходим на [**Git - Downloading Git**](https://git-scm.com/download/win), отменяем начавшуюся загрузку, переходим по ссылке `32-bit Git for Windows Portable` или `64-bit Git for Windows Portable`, скачивается самораспаковывающийся архив. Его можно запустить и установить в произвольную папку, или открыть архиватором и распаковать вручную.

Дальше просто запускаем `git-bash.exe` или `git-cmd.exe`, переходим с помощью команды `cd` в нужную папку, делаем в ней `git clone ...` и т.д.

Естественно, удобств графического интерфейса, которые предоставляет клиент от Github, у вас не будет, но по крайней мере можно будет работать с Git.

Comment: Только хотел эту ссылку дать ))

Comment: не получится, нужны будут права админа, чтобы запустить ехе файл

Comment: @Gusto, если у вас все настолько жестко, что не даст запустить git-bash или git-cmd, то тут уж мы вам никак не сможем помочь. Здесь нужно обращаться к админам учебного заведения, и доказывать, что вам нужен git.

Comment: @Gusto в вопросе у вас упоминается запрет на всего лишь установку, а в этом комментарии запрет на запуск exe-файлов вообще. Так какое именно ограничение-то действует? Лично я в учебном заведении без прав админа exe-файлы успешно запускал.

Comment: @Gusto а как вы хотя бы блокнот или браузер запускаете? Это тоже exe-файлы.

Comment: @NickVolynkin, ну может там разрешение на запуск по белому-списку. Не понятно только как они там кодят, хотя если на интерпретируемых языках - то еще как-то можно.

Comment: @Gusto если что, право устанавливать ≠ право запускать. Точно нельзя будет запустить? Проверьте, пожалуйста.

Comment: @insolor вся эта история мне напоминает мою школьную библиотекаршу, которая не выдавала книжки, которые задали читать по литературе, потому-де они сатанинские. Например, Мастера и Маргариту. :)

Comment: @insolor всё возможно, но пока автор немного путается в показаниях, хочется знать точно что именно ограничивается)

Comment: ok, завтра попробую Portable версию запустить, спс!